How to resolve Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes in android test
I am trying to test a ViewModel that uses LiveData and i'm really hating android right now.
This is the most recent error that I'm getting,
Mockito cannot mock this class: class com.example.encryptednotes.data.MemoRepository.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.

IMPORTANT INFORMATION FOR ANDROID USERS:

The regular Byte Buddy mock makers cannot generate code on an Android VM!
To resolve this, please use the 'mockito-android' dependency for your application:
...
Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke BaseDexClassLoader#addDexPath
...

This is the line of code it is being thrown on
mockRepository = Mockito.mock(MemoRepository::class.java)
And this is that class's declaration
open class MemoRepository(private val memoDao: MemoDao) {
And this is what my test dependencies look like at the moment.
//    androidTestImplementation(libs.mockito.core)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.core.testing)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.robolectric)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.test)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.mockito.mockito.android)

I've been going through dependency hell trying to fix this, your help will be much appreciated!

Have MemoRepository implement an interface that defines the API. Have consumers reference the interface (e.g., have your dependency inversion framework supply the implementation). Then use the interface for test doubles (mocks, fakes, etc.). FWIW, I'm confused by androidTestImplementation(libs.robolectric), as I usually think of Robolectric being for unit tests, not instrumented tests.
